# Get claims from JWT token in ASP.NET Core 2.0 API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using mixed authentication in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web and API app. Meaning both cookies and now adding `JWT token`.

The web part of the app uses cookies and in the API part, I want to use JWT token.

My question is how do I get the claims from `JWT token`? In my web controllers, I can simply use `HttpContext.User;` to get the claims stored in a cookie. How do I handle it in my API methods where I want to use `JWT token`?

Here's my AuthenticationBuilder:

```
public static void MyAuthenticationConfig(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "myApp_cookie";
      options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "myApp_cookie";
    })
    .AddCookie("myApp_cookie", options =>
    {
      options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Unauthorized";
      options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    })
    .AddCookie("social_auth_cookie")
    .AddOAuth("LinkedIn", options =>
    {
      options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";

      options.ClientId = "my_client_id";
      options.ClientSecret = "my_secret";

      options.CallbackPath = "/linkedin-callback";

      options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
      options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
      options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))";

      options.Scope.Add("r_basicprofile");
      options.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");

      options.Events = new OAuthEvents
      {
         OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallBack,
         OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
       };
    })
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";
        options.AppId = "my_app_is";
        options.AppSecret = "my_secret";
        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
           OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketFacebookCallback,
           OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
         };
     })
     .AddGoogle(options =>
     {
         options.SignInScheme = "social_auth_cookie";
         options.ClientId = "my_id.apps.googleusercontent.com";
         options.ClientSecret = "my_secret";
         options.CallbackPath = "/google-callback";
         options.Events = new OAuthEvents
         {
             OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketGoogleCallback,
             OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
         };
      })
      .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", jwtBearerOptions =>
      {
         jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_secret")),

             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidIssuer = "my-api",

             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidAudience = "my-client",

             ValidateLifetime = true,

             ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Normally the claims of JWT are automatically added to the ClaimsIdentity.

Source:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/af5e5c2b0100e8348c63e2d2bb45612e2080841e/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L1110).

So you should be able to just use 'User' property of the base 'Controller' class.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    // TODO Move 'Claims' extraction code to an extension method
    var address = User.Claims.Where('GET THE NEEDED CLAIM');
    ...
}
```

I never had any problems getting the claims from a JWT token.
But I only used *IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation* so far. But internally it uses the Microsoft JWT Handler afaik.

Comment: Can I use IsInRole on HttpContext.User.Identity?

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't comment because my post would be to long, so making a seperate post instead.

If you follow the guide/link ErazerBrecht posted, the claims are indeed stored in the ClaimsPrincipal User. I created an extension method to retrieve the claim.

Note that I use an Enum for registering my claims. I use a dictionary to pass my claims to the method that generates my token, so my claim key should always be unique.

The extension method:

```
public static string GetClaim(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, JwtClaim jwtClaim)
{
  var claim = claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == jwtClaim.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

  if (claim == null)
  {
      throw new JwtClaimNotFoundException(jwtClaim);
  }

  return claim.Value;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var userId = User.GetClaim(JwtClaim.UserId);
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault().Value will throw an exception if the claim is not found.  I suggest moving the .Value to your return statement instead. (return claim.Value) . Then you are checking if the claim is null not if the value of the claim is null.

Comment: You are right, I found this out when I was testing the code today! Along with another bug. nameof() should be replaced by ToString(), as we want to value of the variable, not the name! I will edit the post to reflect this. Guess I should write unit tests straight away!